MOSFET Common-Source Stage with Resistive Load
If the \$V_\text{GS}\$ is constant, the graph,

drain current is as shown. If \$V_\text{GS}\$ varies, the drain current is as shown

My question is, what actually is a saturion region for MOSFET? Why does in 2, the current \$V_\text{DD}/R_\text{D}\$ is greater than saturation current(at \$V_\text{DS}=0+\$)? Then, does at \$V_\text{OUT}=0\$, the current os maximum in 2, as Id(max) always occurs at saturation?

Saturation region for MOSFET is when \$V_\text{DS} > (V_{\text{GST}}-V_\text{TH}\$)
If you provide a constant \$V_\text{GS}\$ to the MOSFET, the drain current in linear region (i.e. when, \$V_\text{DS}<V_\text{GST}-V_\text{TH})\$ will be lower than in saturation region.
However, here in the second plot, you are varying \$V_\text{GS}\$ and that is why the drain current is highest when \$V_\text{DS}\$ is close to 0V. \$V_\text{GS}\$ is the highest at this point and the MOSFET is acting like a resistor of a very small value (like a switch).
So, in summary, saturation region current is higher than current in linear region only if the \$V_\text{GS}\$ is same for both cases. You cannot compare the saturation current at a lower \$V_\text{GS}\$ to a linear region current at a higher \$V_\text{GS}\$.

Thank you for your support
